# Add controller is greyed in Visual Studio Asp.net Core 1.0 MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I am following the Microsoft 'first-mvc-app' tutorial from [here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model.html). When I try to add a controller class to the model folder, I can't add it. The add button is greyed out and doesn't give a reason for it. I followed the tutorial to the T so I think something is different with my setup. I am running Visual Studio 2015 with the latest updates and I am using MVC 1.0 RC2.

Comment: Shouldn't you be adding a _controller_ to the **Controllers** folder?

Answer (score 3):

You need to Shift-F5 to end debug and it will not be greyed out.

Answer (score 0):

Try filling the forms like "Model Class" by selecting from the dropdown lists instead of directly entering text. This activated the "Add" button in my case.